# Get attribute of child element for CSS value

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML to display some images.

```
<ul id="stage" class="fading-slideshow" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px;">
  <li title="France (2011)"><img src="2011-09-19 16.45.51 - P1000359.JPG" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""></li>
  <li title="Test caption 1"><img src="DSC00008.JPG" alt=""></li>
  <li title="Test caption 2"><img src="DSC00013.JPG" alt=""></li>
  <li title="Test caption 3"><img src="DSC00046.JPG" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

And I am using the following CSS to add a caption to the images:

```
#stage li::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    width: calc(100% - 4px);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    content: attr(title);
    font-size: 2.0em;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Everything is working as expected, however I would prefer to put the `title` attribute in the `<img>` tag rather than in the `<li>` tag.

The CSS `content: attr(title);` gets the title from the element that is being selected - ie the `li`, but if I move the title attribute to the `img` tag, is there a way to select the title from there using `first-child` or something similar?

I can't find any examples of using selectors in CSS values like this, so maybe it's not possible...

Comment: it's not possible

Comment: Would probably make more sense to include those captions as actual HTML content in the first place. Why not use something, that makes a bit more sense semantically? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Comment: @CBroe No need to worry about semantics in this use case - it's for a closed system, kisosk type slideshow display so no varying displays or user interaction. However, in terms of shuffling the order of slides it would make more sense to keep the caption with the image tag rather than the list item tag. It doesn't make a big difference, just trying to avoid my own copy/paste mistakes.

Comment: This could only be done with Javascript tbh

Comment: Would it help to use the figure element with figcaption - just as a way of keeping the img and its caption together as one unit?

Comment: @AHaworth I wasn't aware of the `figure tag! How did I miss that? I don't think it would help in this case (although it would be a more logical wrapper than the `li` wrappers that I'm using now) but certainly good to know about for the future.